# How do I setup hg Mercurial to do an automatic commit on file save?

Tags: save, mercurial, commit, tortoisehg, autosave

If I have a repository like this:

```
C:\repository\
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    file3.txt
```

how can I configure or setup hg such that every time I save any one of those files hg will automatically commit the new saved version of the file to the repository revision history?

Comment: I'm curious what the situation is where you would want to do this. That could result in an awful lot of commits, many trivial.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Yes, you are correct, and it could also, in theory, end up in an infinite loop of committing, detecting a change (from the commit action), then committing again...if done carelessly. My reasoning is a combination of my aversion to data loss (read: loss of work done) and efficiency (spelled "l-a-z-i-n-e-s-s"). If the commit is trivial, the space it takes is trivial...but I am open to being convinced otherwise.

Comment: I actually think its an interesting experiment. You're right that the individual commits should be tiny. One thought is that before pushing changes to anyone else you might need a step to squash all those individual save commits.

Comment: Your comment reminded me that I left out one key aspect - I'm using it as a local CVS, not a DVS...but you raised an interesting and important point if considering this in a DVS scenario. That makes me think of the possibility of timed commits (like autosave every X minutes) and also how to aggregate multiple saves to one auto commit and how aggregation might work.

Comment: Using a timer you could just issue a commit every so often. If there were no changes, then no commit. This might mean direct HG integration is unnecessary, and could be simpler (?)

Comment: Using inotify should help.